# Ambiguous tag [adhoc]

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

The tag [adhoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adhoc) is currently being used for general "ad hoc solutions" and "iOS Ad Hoc provisioning".

The tag wiki currently refers to "ad hoc solutions", but there are a lot of iOS-related posts with this tag.

I suggest to create separate tags [adhoc-ios](/questions/tagged/adhoc-ios) and [adhoc-solution](/questions/tagged/adhoc-solution) or any other tags that would imply the correct information.

Comment: The latter would be a meta-tag which should be destroyed.

Comment: It is such a small tag.  There's only one SO user with a substantial number of answers and he already filters with [android].  It is just a contextual tag, no point in breaking it up.